# Canopy configuration / preferences directory

Tags: configuration, osx-mavericks, enthought, canopy

I'm running Canopy 64-bit as my IDE on my osX 10.9 and I wanted to do a clean uninstall but I can't seem to find this [directory](http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/faq.html#where-are-the-preference-and-log-files-located) which Canopy says it holds configuration/preferences directory. Anybody knows where it might be embedded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `~/.canopy`

From the user guide:

http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/faq.html#where-are-the-preference-and-log-files-located

Comment: ok got it, I had to put the exact directory location to reveal the contents of this folder, bit of a clean up if you want to get rid of everything... leaves traces

Comment: To delete the folder and all its contents from a terminal: `rm -rf ~/.canopy`